# writing data from json to java object using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have been using jackson library to read data from input stream to java object.

the code is as follows:

**json is string in which data is in the form of JSON**

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));

 String json = "";

 json = br.readLine();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper():
Position position = mapper.readValue(json, Position.class);
```

where Position is a plain getter setter class. Now when I write data to a file using

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("E://out.txt");
writer.write(position.getMobile());
writer.close();
```

It will not writing any data on text file, neither the file is creating.

One thing more, if I only write json as it is to file , it is ok. i mean it is writing the json string in the form of JSON to file.

Comment: What does the JSON contain, what does `getAnyMethod` do? Don't post pseudo code. Show us exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Just feed `ObjectMapper` with an `InputStream` from the file itself; you don't need to read the string. Especially since you forget to specify an encoding...

Comment: i have done whatever @fge said i.e.  '        
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Position po = mapper.readValue( request.getInputStream(),Position.class);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("E://out.txt");
            writer.write(po.getMobile());
          writer.write(po.getPassword());
           writer.close(); '   but it doesn't works for me.

Comment: That's a little vague. Exception? Output?

Comment: no exception. but it is conformed that error is in parsing bcoz if i write json string to file , there is no problem, but if i am parsing it using above code. nothing is being written to the file.

Comment: just got my mistake, actually in Position class i have written different order of getter setter methods from the one that i was recieving from json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a little example, it worked fine for me.

The Domain class: Position

```
package de.professional_webworkx.jackson.jacksondemo.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Random;

public class Position implements Serializable {

private Long id;
private double lat;
private double lon;

protected Position() {}

public Position(final double lat, final double lon) {
    this.id     = generateId();
    this.lat    = lat;
    this.lon    = lon;
}

private Long generateId() {
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    return random.nextLong();
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public double getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(double lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public double getLon() {
    return lon;
}

public void setLon(double lon) {
    this.lon = lon;
}
```

}

And start the app

```
package de.professional_webworkx.jackson.jacksondemo;

import de.professional_webworkx.jackson.jacksondemo.domain.Person;
import de.professional_webworkx.jackson.jacksondemo.domain.Position;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class App {

    public static final File FILENAME = new File("position.json");

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(1980, 1, 1);
        Person person = new Person("Patrick", "Ott", "patrick.ott@professional-webworkx.de");

        Position position = new Position(48.113345, 11.273829);

        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.writeValue(FILENAME, position);
            // here i read the position from the *.json file
            Position readValue = mapper.readValue(FILENAME, Position.class);
            System.out.println(readValue.getLat() + "N, " + readValue.getLon() + "E" );
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

if you need the dependencies for your pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Here is the result:

```
{"id":5799095657619062507,"lat":48.113345,"lon":11.273829}
```